# VBA Excel GetObject Issue - Run Time Error 91 - Object Variable or With block Variable not Set

Tags: vba, excel, object, catia

I am getting an error:

> "Run-Time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set" .

Debugging highlights the line with `MsgBox()`:

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application    
    Set xlApp = VBA.GetObject("", "Excel.Application")    
    Dim exlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Set exlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook    
    MsgBox exlBook.Name

End Sub
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `""` from your code in `VBA.GetObject()` and it should work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application        
    Set xlApp = VBA.GetObject(, "Excel.Application")        
    Dim exlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Set exlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook        
    MsgBox exlBook.Name

End Sub
```

[MSDN GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getobject-function). These are the parameters of `GetObject()`:

- **pathname**   - Optional; Variant ( String ). The full path and name of the file containing the object to retrieve. If pathname is omitted, class is required.
- **class** Optional; Variant ( String ). A string representing theclass of the object.

Comment: If I do that, another error occurs. "Run-time error 429: ActiveX  component  can't create object"

Comment: @ccan - strange. Did you put the code in Excel, it worked quite ok with me. Or is it in `Catia`?

Comment: Yes I made my code work in Excel but I want to make it work in Catia.

Comment: When I made the code work in excel, the code was a little bit different. The code configuration was inverse. It didn't need the line `Set xlApp = VBA.GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` , instead, somewhere in the code there was `Set CATIA = VBA.GetObject("", "CATIA.Application")` .

Comment: @ccan - Idk about `Catia`, but I guess that the `""` should not work there as well. However, if you close all the apps of your PC and you open one Excel, the code above would work. It really depends from what app are you calling it. I guess it does not have much sense to call it from Excel, but still it would work.

Comment: @Vityaya I will go on trying. Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe there isn't a workbook opened and´xlApp.ActiveWorkbook´ is indeed returning a null workbook? Try checking before, something like: `if xlApp.Workbooks.count = 0 then xlApp.Workbooks.add`.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution (with Excel already opened), in addition to adding a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library in Catia VBA, does work on Catia R2015.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
 xlApp.Application.Visible = True
```

after set ...

You'll see why there's no activeworkbook.name

Because of the "" you open a new instance

Comment: How can I make it read the active document? I thought "GetObject" should do that.

Answer (score 0):

In a CATIA vb module:

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim xlApp As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = VBA.GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (xlApp Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Please start MS Excel prior running this script!!", vbCritical, "Excel not started"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim exlBook As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set exlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (exlBook Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "No Workbook is openned", vbExclamation, "MS Excel is empty"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox exlBook.Name

End Sub
```